# ChaCha20 core vs ideal unkeyed PRP

Tags: chacha, arx

I know that the ChaCha20 core (without the initial constant) is not an ideal PRP and must not be used as such.  I also know that $\text{ChaChaCore}(0) = 0$.  Are there any other differences?

Comment: 1) I think the ChaCha(0)=0 property generalizes to all words being identical. 2) ChaCha has obvious rotational symmetries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be extremily surprising if the ChaCha core was a *permutation* (as the last P in PRP), although we have no proof it is not (if it was a permutation, it would at least be one we do not known how to invert, see this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26437/555)).

A better approximation is that the ChaCha core behaves as a Pseudo-Random Function with the additional property $\text{ChaChaCore}(0)=0$. When we use as part of the input a constant secret key, the ChaCha core becomes a plausible Pseudo Random Function family.

The ChaCha core has less remarkable externally visible properties than the Salsa20 core has. $\text{ChaChaCore}(0)=0$ is a simple one. There are however others, including keeping some symmetries in the input into the output; and other properties that a true PRF would not have.

In particular: by definition, $\text{ChaChaCore}(x)=P(x)\boxplus x$ where $\boxplus$ is 512-bit addition with carry removed between 32-bit chunks, and $P$ is some public permutation (with $P(0)=0$) that can be trivially inverted. It follows that knowledge of $\text{ChaChaCore}(x)\boxminus x$ is enough to find $x$, by computing $P^{-1}(\text{ChaChaCore}(x)\boxminus x)$, where $\boxminus$ is to $\boxplus$ what subtraction is to addition.

Comment: I think the OP considers ChaCha without the final addition when they talk about the core.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: perhaps the OP considers ChaCha without the final $\boxplus$; but unambiguously, the Salsa20 core includes $\boxplus$, and I see that a lot for the term Chacha core; e.g. [here](http://2014.diac.cr.yp.to/slides/krovetz-hs1.pdf#page=8); [here](https://github.com/bsdphk/PHC/blob/master/OmegaCrypt/nettle-chacha/chacha-core-internal.c#L84); and even arguably by the author [here](https://cr.yp.to/chacha.html).

Comment: @fgrieu yes I was referring to the case where the final ⊞ is omitted.