# How fast does a pseudorandom number generator have to be in order to be competitive?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

Let $\{x_n\}_{n}$ be the pseudorandom sequence produced by a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator $G$. What is the cost of computing a term in the sequence for a competitive pseudorandom number generator (PRNG)?

Let me clarify: among the cryptographically secure PRNG, I would like to know which one has the lowest computational cost.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On modern CPUs, a fast Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator runs sizably faster than one cycle per byte. We are talking >40Gbit/s. See numbers [there](https://bench.cr.yp.to/results-stream.html). Top contenders are [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)-[CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#CTR) assisted by special instructions, and [ARX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher#ARX_(add%E2%80%93rotate%E2%80%93xor)) ciphers like [ChaCha](https://cr.yp.to/chacha.html).

When using dedicated hardware, the true limit is moving around the generated random bits. We can arbitrarily parallelize CSPRNGs, and we have many efficient designs. For example, [Trivium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivium_(cipher)) is [reported](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/e2-trivium.html) at >120Gbit/s/mm<sup>2</sup> using 250nm metal CMOS technology, and state of the art today is about 10nm technology, which is faster and some hundreds time denser.

---

Update per [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/138736): All modern CSPRNGs require $O(n)$ bit operations to produce $n$ bits, and we want a more precise estimate. [ChaCha](https://cr.yp.to/chacha.html) with $r$ rounds (see [source](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26437/555)) produces $16$ words each 32-bit with computational cost dominated by $16(r+1)$ 32-bit additions and $16r$ 32-bit XORs. Using NAND gates, a [ripple-carry adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Ripple-carry_adder) is 9 gates, XOR is 4 gates, thus the cost is $13r+9$ NAND bit operations per bit produced. For ChaCha8 (which is hoped to have at least 128-bit security), the cost is $\approx113n$ NAND bit operations to produce $n$ bits (with no consideration for circuit depth).

---

Update on the security of ChaCha8 per this [other comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/138761?noredirect=1): I'm reasonably confident that ChaCha8 is at least 128-bit safe, but reluctant to state much more because

- ChaCha is an evolution of Salsa20, with the same number of 32-bit additions and XORs, and a faster diffusion. While that could make it safer, I'm using that as safety margin.
- In the abstract of the [Salsa paper](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle/salsafamily-20071225.pdf), Daniel J. Bernstein recommends the 20-round version for typical applications, and presents 12 and 8-round variants as *reduced-round* versions recommended *for applications where speed is more important than confidence*.
- Salsa20 was proposed for eSTREAM, in the category asking for fast software ciphers with 128-bit security. While DJB presents Salsa20/20, Salsa20/12 and Salsa20/8 as 256-bit ciphers (which they are as far as key size goes), I'm not reading him as claiming 256-bit security, especially for the reduced-round versions.
- There is a known attack with complexity $\approx2^{249}$ against Salsa20/8, thus definitely it does not have security matching its key size. Again, ChaCha8 differs only by its diffusion pattern.
- There is a known attack with complexity $\approx2^{153}$ against Salsa20/7, and as the saying goes: attacks only get better; they never get worse.

Comment: Thanks for this. In terms of big O notation, how many bit operations does chacha requires for example to produce an n-bit pseudoradom number?

Comment: @forest: see new section in the answer. I'll remove this comment after you could read it.

Comment: I believe djb (the creator of Salsa and ChaCha) considers all 128-bit-key symmetric primitives to have less than 128-bit security [due to multi-target attacks](https://blog.cr.yp.to/20151120-batchattacks.html). Hence djb always recommends 256-bit symmetric keys but doesn’t necessarily claim 256-bit security.

Answer (score -3):

It sort of depends on what you are using it for.
You would think that openssl's PRNG, rand, would be
cryptographically secure, and I'm sure it's plenty fast.
But I couldn't help but notice a regular preponderance
of repeated hex digits in every call to openssl rand, using
a value of 16 (for AES 128 purposes).  Given that the average
intel chip comes with AES round calculations in silicon, for
extra speed, it does seem like the search space for brute
forcing AES (without the benefit of the RSA-encrypted key)
has been made smaller by this repetition.

If you know that 3 of your 32 4-bit possibilities will
be repeated FOUR times (or more!) you do save some time
doing a brute force.  If I knew in advance that 31 of
the 32 nybbles would be repeated, I would only have to
check 4096 different keys. (as an extreme example)

I once counted 9 repeated digits on one generation.
I know the goal is for a *random* distribution, but
when you only have 128 bits, that's not always good enough.

So I imagine even at mind-blowing speeds, there's room for
side-channel surprises.  Good luck!

Here's some results I just generated on the fly:

```
user0@ii:~$ openssl rand 16 -hex
0fe29badfe8e2300cbe4d1f0eecfdac1
000011223489aabbcccdddEEEEEEffff (6,4x2)

user0@ii:~$ openssl rand 16 -hex
a6f3b7054138c58991b560b6377a567f
001133345555666677778899aabbbcff (4x3)

user0@ii:~$ openssl rand 16 -hex
c2d854a9fdac7e73a9872c12ade2c048
012222344577788899aaaaccccdddeef (4x3)

user0@ii:~$ openssl rand 16 -hex
7e1a3400da787aff51dbddd2fd10067a
00001112345677778aaaabDDDDDDefff (6,4x3)

user0@ii:~$ openssl rand 16 -hex
4785496843d62083ed285572cd1ad6b2
012222334445556667788889abcdddde (4x3)
```

Comment: I believe that a truly random output would show the same artifacts that you complain about OpenSSL; for example, a truly random 16 byte output would have 9 or repeated hex digits once every circa 370000 outputs.  So, yes, if you go through enough of them, you would expect to see such extreme cases (and 'enough' needn't be that many...)

Comment: You're falling into a trap. I recall a complaint that consecutive second factor codes repeated a few digits and so it was not truly random. Something like "182345" and "405346" - there's a repeat of "34". Just because something stands out to you does not mean it is not random. Humans are great at seeing patterns including the ones that don't exist.

Comment: If you're suggesting that OpenSSL's PRNG is inadequate because it shows patterns, then this answer needs to be improved by including an analysis showing that the patterns are statistically significant.

Comment: I agree that seeing "34" like that in two outputs would be "reading a lot into it."  But if you see "34" in 6 out of 6 outputs, I'd say you've reduced your brute force effort by a factor of 100.  Of course, you're betting that the 7th will have a "34" and it's always possible that it was just pure randomness (I understand the counterintuitive qualities of pure random values).  I'm just saying that if I were designing a PRNG system, I would work hard to avoid such coincidences.  And yes, I know how naive that sounds.  Sorry about the lack of math proof.

Comment: In my defense, I cranked out a simple 128-bit PRNG using glibc's rand() and concatenating 4 of them and printing.  "noticeably" fewer repeats.  Why? not sure.  Mine just seems more random, and hence, harder to crack.  If you want "math", you could always "do the math" and extrapolate from my "31-out-of-32" example, which is real math.

Comment: `1dfbbfb05c61b06846f33be25ecfbba7
001123345566678aBBBBBBBccdeeffff (7,4)

68e9a9046e6c510367e88c733178a34f
001133334456666777888899aacceeef (4x3)

62e7174343ce637b13a80d2a0786557b
001122333344556667777788aabbcdee (5,4)

540447db380be3bb65e8ab0b4771d353
000133334444555677788aBBBBBBddee (6,4x2)

62ab103319834a906e82ecaf21bd10e2
000111122223334668899aaabbcdeeef (4x2)

28c9b1db46f466766368e329608ffebe
012233446666666788899bbbcdeeefff (7)
`